# Error on line 3, column 1 of pubspec.lock: Only expected one document

Tags: flutter, dart

I get an error when trying to start the flutter project.

```
    [modules/common_library] flutter pub get
Running "flutter pub get" in common_library...                  
Error on line 3, column 1 of pubspec.lock: Only expected one document.

    ╷
3   │ ┌ packages:
4   │ │   args:



5   │ │     dependency: transitive

6   │ │     description:

7   │ │       name: args

8   │ │       url: "https://pub.dartlang.org"
9   │ │     source: hosted
10  │ │     version: "2.1.0"




11  │ │   asn1lib:
12  │ │     dependency: transitive
13  │ │     description:


14  │ │       name: asn1lib
15  │ │       url: "https://pub.dartlang.org"


16  │ │     source: hosted
17  │ │     version: "1.0.0"


18  │ │   async:


19  │ │     dependency: transitive
20  │ │     description:


21  │ │       name: async
22  │ │       url: "https://pub.dartlang.org"
23  │ │     source: hosted


24  │ │     version: "2.6.1"


25  │ │   characters:
26  │ │     dependency: transitive


27  │ │     description:
28  │ │       name: characters


29  │ │       url: "https://pub.dartlang.org"
30  │ │     source: hosted
31  │ │     version: "1.1.0"



32  │ │   charcode:
33  │ │     dependency: transitive


34  │ │     description:
35  │ │       name: charcode


36  │ │       url: "https://pub.dartlang.org"
37  │ │     source: hosted

38  │ │     version: "1.2.0"
39  │ │   clock:
40  │ │     dependency: transitive



41  │ │     description:
42  │ │       name: clock


43  │ │       url: "https://pub.dartlang.org"
44  │ │     source: hosted


45  │ │     version: "1.1.0"
46  │ │   collection:


47  │ │     dependency: transitive
48  │ │     description:


49  │ │       name: collection

50  │ │       url: "https://pub.dartlang.org"

51  │ │     source: hosted


52  │ │     version: "1.15.0"
53  │ │   crypto:


54  │ │     dependency: transitive
55  │ │     description:

56  │ │       name: crypto
57  │ │       url: "https://pub.dartlang.org"



58  │ │     source: hosted
59  │ │     version: "3.0.1"


60  │ │   cupertino_icons:
61  │ │     dependency: transitive






62  │ │     description:
63  │ │       name: cupertino_icons
64  │ │       url: "https://pub.dartlang.org"
65  │ │     source: hosted
66  │ │     version: "1.0.3"
67  │ │   dio:
68  │ │     dependency: "direct main"


69  │ │     description:
70  │ │       name: dio


71  │ │       url: "https://pub.dartlang.org"
72  │ │     source: hosted


73  │ │     version: "4.0.0"


74  │ │   encrypt:
75  │ │     dependency: "direct main"


76  │ │     description:
77  │ │       name: encrypt


78  │ │       url: "https://pub.dartlang.org"
79  │ │     source: hosted


80  │ │     version: "5.0.0"
81  │ │   event_bus:

82  │ │     dependency: "direct main"
83  │ │     description:


84  │ │       name: event_bus

85  │ │       url: "https://pub.dartlang.org"

86  │ │     source: hosted

87  │ │     version: "2.0.0"
88  │ │   extended_image:


89  │ │     dependency: "direct main"

90  │ │     description:

91  │ │       name: extended_image

92  │ │       url: "https://pub.dartlang.org"

93  │ │     source: hosted

94  │ │     version: "4.1.0"

95  │ │   extended_image_library:

96  │ │     dependency: transitive

97  │ │     description:

98  │ │       name: extended_image_library


99  │ │       url: "https://pub.dartlang.org"
100 │ │     source: hosted

101 │ │     version: "3.1.0"
102 │ │   ffi:


103 │ │     dependency: transitive

104 │ │     description:

105 │ │       name: ffi

106 │ │       url: "https://pub.dartlang.org"
107 │ │     source: hosted


108 │ │     version: "1.0.0"


109 │ │   file:
110 │ │     dependency: transitive

111 │ │     description:

112 │ │       name: file
113 │ │       url: "https://pub.dartlang.org"


114 │ │     source: hosted

115 │ │     version: "6.1.0"

116 │ │   flutter:

117 │ │     dependency: "direct main"

118 │ │     description: flutter

119 │ │     source: sdk

120 │ │     version: "0.0.0"

121 │ │   flutter_iconpicker:
122 │ │     dependency: "direct main"



123 │ │     description:
124 │ │       name: flutter_iconpicker

125 │ │       url: "https://pub.dartlang.org"


126 │ │     source: hosted
127 │ │     version: "3.0.1+2"


128 │ │   font_awesome_flutter:
129 │ │     dependency: transitive

130 │ │     description:

131 │ │       name: font_awesome_flutter

132 │ │       url: "https://pub.dartlang.org"

133 │ │     source: hosted

134 │ │     version: "9.0.0"

135 │ │   google_fonts:

136 │ │     dependency: "direct main"



137 │ │     description:
138 │ │       name: google_fonts
139 │ │       url: "https://pub.dartlang.org"

140 │ │     source: hosted


141 │ │     version: "2.1.0"
142 │ │   http:


143 │ │     dependency: transitive
144 │ │     description:


145 │ │       name: http
146 │ │       url: "https://pub.dartlang.org"


147 │ │     source: hosted
148 │ │     version: "0.13.3"

149 │ │   http_client_helper:

150 │ │     dependency: transitive
151 │ │     description:
152 │ │       name: http_client_helper




153 │ │       url: "https://pub.dartlang.org"
154 │ │     source: hosted

155 │ │     version: "2.0.2"

156 │ │   http_parser:

157 │ │     dependency: transitive


158 │ │     description:
159 │ │       name: http_parser


160 │ │       url: "https://pub.dartlang.org"
161 │ │     source: hosted


162 │ │     version: "4.0.0"
163 │ │   intl:


164 │ │     dependency: "direct main"
165 │ │     description:

166 │ │       name: intl
167 │ │       url: "https://pub.dartlang.org"


168 │ │     source: hosted


169 │ │     version: "0.17.0"
170 │ │   intro_slider:


171 │ │     dependency: "direct main"
172 │ │     description:

173 │ │       name: intro_slider
174 │ │       url: "https://pub.dartlang.org"



175 │ │     source: hosted
176 │ │     version: "2.4.3"


177 │ │   logger:
178 │ │     dependency: "direct main"



179 │ │     description:
180 │ │       name: logger
181 │ │       url: "https://pub.dartlang.org"

182 │ │     source: hosted

183 │ │     version: "1.0.0"






184 │ │   meta:
185 │ │     dependency: transitive
186 │ │     description:
187 │ │       name: meta
188 │ │       url: "https://pub.dartlang.org"
189 │ │     source: hosted

190 │ │     version: "1.3.0"
191 │ │   path:


192 │ │     dependency: transitive

193 │ │     description:

194 │ │       name: path

195 │ │       url: "https://pub.dartlang.org"

196 │ │     source: hosted

197 │ │     version: "1.8.0"

198 │ │   path_provider:

199 │ │     dependency: transitive

200 │ │     description:

201 │ │       name: path_provider

202 │ │       url: "https://pub.dartlang.org"

203 │ │     source: hosted

204 │ │     version: "2.0.1"

205 │ │   path_provider_linux:

206 │ │     dependency: transitive
207 │ │     description:
208 │ │       name: path_provider_linux



209 │ │       url: "https://pub.dartlang.org"




210 │ │     source: hosted
211 │ │     version: "2.0.0"
212 │ │   path_provider_macos:
213 │ │     dependency: transitive


214 │ │     description:
215 │ │       name: path_provider_macos

216 │ │       url: "https://pub.dartlang.org"
217 │ │     source: hosted


218 │ │     version: "2.0.0"

219 │ │   path_provider_platform_interface:

220 │ │     dependency: transitive

221 │ │     description:
222 │ │       name: path_provider_platform_interface


223 │ │       url: "https://pub.dartlang.org"

224 │ │     source: hosted

225 │ │     version: "2.0.1"

226 │ │   path_provider_windows:

227 │ │     dependency: transitive


228 │ │     description:
229 │ │       name: path_provider_windows

230 │ │       url: "https://pub.dartlang.org"

231 │ │     source: hosted


232 │ │     version: "2.0.1"
233 │ │   pedantic:

234 │ │     dependency: "direct main"
235 │ │     description:


236 │ │       name: pedantic

237 │ │       url: "https://pub.dartlang.org"

238 │ │     source: hosted

239 │ │     version: "1.11.0"
240 │ │   platform:





241 │ │     dependency: transitive
242 │ │     description:
243 │ │       name: platform
244 │ │       url: "https://pub.dartlang.org"

245 │ │     source: hosted

246 │ │     version: "3.0.0"
247 │ │   plugin_platform_interface:


248 │ │     dependency: transitive
249 │ │     description:


250 │ │       name: plugin_platform_interface
251 │ │       url: "https://pub.dartlang.org"


252 │ │     source: hosted
253 │ │     version: "2.0.0"


254 │ │   pointycastle:


255 │ │     dependency: transitive
256 │ │     description:

257 │ │       name: pointycastle
258 │ │       url: "https://pub.dartlang.org"


259 │ │     source: hosted

260 │ │     version: "3.0.1"

261 │ │   process:

262 │ │     dependency: transitive

263 │ │     description:

264 │ │       name: process

265 │ │       url: "https://pub.dartlang.org"

266 │ │     source: hosted
267 │ │     version: "4.2.1"


268 │ │   sky_engine:
269 │ │     dependency: transitive


270 │ │     description: flutter

271 │ │     source: sdk

272 │ │     version: "0.0.99"
273 │ │   source_span:


274 │ │     dependency: transitive

275 │ │     description:


276 │ │       name: source_span
277 │ │       url: "https://pub.dartlang.org"

278 │ │     source: hosted


279 │ │     version: "1.8.1"
280 │ │   string_scanner:

281 │ │     dependency: transitive

282 │ │     description:

283 │ │       name: string_scanner

284 │ │       url: "https://pub.dartlang.org"

285 │ │     source: hosted
286 │ │     version: "1.1.0"


287 │ │   term_glyph:


288 │ │     dependency: transitive
289 │ │     description:


290 │ │       name: term_glyph
291 │ │       url: "https://pub.dartlang.org"
292 │ │     source: hosted


293 │ │     version: "1.2.0"


294 │ │   timeago:
295 │ │     dependency: "direct main"
296 │ │     description:


297 │ │       name: timeago

298 │ │       url: "https://pub.dartlang.org"
299 │ │     source: hosted


300 │ │     version: "3.0.2"
301 │ │   typed_data:


302 │ │     dependency: transitive
303 │ │     description:


304 │ │       name: typed_data
305 │ │       url: "https://pub.dartlang.org"


306 │ │     source: hosted

307 │ │     version: "1.3.0"

308 │ │   vector_math:

309 │ │     dependency: transitive

310 │ │     description:

311 │ │       name: vector_math
312 │ │       url: "https://pub.dartlang.org"


313 │ │     source: hosted

314 │ │     version: "2.1.0"

315 │ │   win32:
316 │ │     dependency: transitive


317 │ │     description:


318 │ │       name: win32
319 │ │       url: "https://pub.dartlang.org"

320 │ │     source: hosted
321 │ │     version: "2.0.5"


322 │ │   xdg_directories:
323 │ │     dependency: transitive


324 │ │     description:

325 │ │       name: xdg_directories
326 │ │       url: "https://pub.dartlang.org"


327 │ │     source: hosted


328 │ │     version: "0.2.0"
329 │ │ sdks:


330 │ │   dart: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"
331 │ └   flutter: ">=1.20.0"
    ╵

pub get failed (65;     ╵)
exit code 65
```

can you please help me to fix it.
I use a MacBook air with an m1 chip. I run many flutter projects with no issue.

```
flutter doctor -v
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.2.3, on macOS 11.5.1 20G80 darwin-arm, locale en-KW)
    • Flutter version 2.2.3 at /Users/mac/FlutterDev/flutter
    • Framework revision f4abaa0735 (7 weeks ago), 2021-07-01 12:46:11 -0700
    • Engine revision 241c87ad80
    • Dart version 2.13.4

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 31.0.0)
    • Android SDK at /Users/mac/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-31, build-tools 31.0.0
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio Preview.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.10+0-b96-7281165)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 12.5.1, Build version 12E507
    • CocoaPods version 1.10.2

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio Preview.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.10+0-b96-7281165)

[✓] Connected device (2 available)
    • macOS (desktop) • macos  • darwin-arm64   • macOS 11.5.1 20G80 darwin-arm
    • Chrome (web)    • chrome • web-javascript • Google Chrome 92.0.4515.159

• No issues found!
```

Answer (score 1):

Delete your *pubspec.lock* file and run `flutter pub get` again.

Comment: Can you share your *pubspec.yaml* file?